# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined in AOS animation

Tags: reactjs

Guys I'm trying to use the animation animation but when configuring my effect I run into the error

**Cannot read property 'type' of undefined**
Occurred while linting C:\Users\paulo_9bquoem\Desktop\my-app\src\Pages\principal\index.js:15

```
  **useEffect( () => {
    Aos.init({duration : 2000});    **line 15 where it says is the error**
  }, []);**
```

https://github.com/joaupaulo/nutri/blob/master/src/Pages/principal/index.js  full error page on github

Answer (score 1):

After checking your code, I think the version you are using for AOS is not stable.

Here you go:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Aos from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    Aos.init({ duration: 2000 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        {" "}
        <nav>
          <div>
            {" "}
            <h1> Monica Nunes </h1>
            <h3>Nutricionista</h3>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a>home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a>serviços</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a>blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a>quem é monica nunes ? </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div className="socialink">
            <i
              href="https://www.facebook.com/"
              className="fab fa-facebook-f"
            ></i>
            <i
              href="https://www.instagram.com/joaupaulo_/"
              className="fab fa-instagram"
            ></i>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </section>
      <div className="banner">
        <div>
          {" "}
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />{" "}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="conteudo">
        <h1> Dieta Fléxivel </h1>
        <h3>
          {" "}
          Você já ouviu falar na <strong> dieta flexível? </strong> Muito famosa
          lá fora e ganhando força no Brasil, ela busca, em vez de focar nas{" "}
          <strong>
            {" "}
            calorias, contabilizar os macronutrientes – proteínas, gorduras e
            carboidratos da alimentação.{" "}
          </strong>{" "}
        </h3>
        <h3>
          Em inglês,{" "}
          <strong> ela é chamada de If it fit your macros (IIFYM),</strong> que
          em tradução livre significa{" "}
          <strong> “se couber nos seus macros[nutrientes]”. </strong>{" "}
        </h3>
        <h3>
          {" "}
          Essa forma de combinar os alimentos permite muito mais flexibilidade,
          pois todos os tipos podem ser apreciados, desde que se encaixem nos
          macros do dia.
        </h3>
        <button>
          {" "}
          <a href="#"> SAIBA MAIS </a>{" "}
        </button>
        <iframe
          width="560"
          height="315"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GTIoj87CR1c"
          frameBorder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowFullScreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>

      <div data-aos="fade-up" className="store">
        <div>
          {" "}
          <h1> MyFitnessPall</h1>{" "}
        </div>
        <h3>
          <strong>calculadora de calorias </strong> mais rápida e fácil de usar,
          100% GRATIS. Com o maior banco de dados de alimentos de qualquer
          contador de calorias{" "}
          <strong> (mais de 5 milhões de alimentos) </strong> , e com registros
          rapidíssimos de alimentos e exercícios, nós vamos ajudá-lo a perder
          peso, ficar em boa forma e manter sua saúde.{" "}
          <strong>
            Não há aplicativo de dieta melhor para emagrecer - ponto final.
          </strong>{" "}
        </h3>
        <div>
          {" "}
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />{" "}
        </div>
        <h3>
          {" "}
          Interface do aplicativo,nesta imagem você pode ver como funciona a
          contagem de calórias{" "}
        </h3>
        <div>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />{" "}
        </div>
        <div>
          {" "}
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
      <iframe
        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d31108.2376293009!2d-38.37842625572786!3d-12.93792038984927!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x7161775f71fcf81%3A0xc5b8bd4b3acc3031!2sItapu%C3%A3%2C%20Salvador%20-%20BA!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1604531782930!5m2!1spt-BR!2sbr"
        width="600"
        height="450"
        frameBorder="0"
        style="border:0;"
        allowFullScreen=""
        aria-hidden="false"
        tabIndex="0"
        style={{ width: "100%", margintop: "100%" }}
      ></iframe>
      <footer>
        <div>
          {" "}
          <h1> M. Nunes </h1>
          <h3>Nutricionista</h3>
        </div>

        <div>
          {" "}
          <h2> INSTITUCIONAL</h2>
          <hr />
          <h3>
            {" "}
            <a href="#"> Quem sou eu ? </a>{" "}
          </h3>
          <h3>
            {" "}
            <a href="#"> Politica de privacidade ? </a>{" "}
          </h3>
          <h3>
            {" "}
            <a href="#"> Termos de uso </a>{" "}
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          {" "}
          <h2> SERVIÇO </h2>
          <hr />
          <h3>
            {" "}
            <a href="#"> Trabalhe conosco </a>{" "}
          </h3>
          <h3>
            {" "}
            <a href="#"> Fale conosco </a>{" "}
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          {" "}
          <h2> CANAIS </h2>
          <hr />
          <div>
            <i
              href="https://www.facebook.com/"
              className="fab fa-facebook-f"
            ></i>
            <i
              href="https://www.instagram.com/joaupaulo_/"
              className="fab fa-instagram"
            ></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am using `v2.3.4`

In addition, please change attributes of your tags to react compatible once, Example: `class` => `className`, `allowfullscreen` => `allowFullScreen`, `tabindex` => `tabIndex`

Please let me know in case you are still facing problem.